# 'Load more' data option

Tags: user-centered-design, content-loading

In a list with loads of records, I have implemented a 'Load more' control for user to load the next batch of records to join the previous visible ones. 
Can't use the pagination as the records need to be accessible easily when loaded completely.

Should the load more button be disabled or hidden on completion of records?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a big fan of disabling the button and leaving up to the user to figure it out.

I always recommend that if all the records are shown, hide the load more button and display a message like: **All records/articles/products/items have been loaded**